# Bash curl command works in terminal, but not with Python os.system()

Tags: python, curl, os.system

I am trying to make a call to get an api token. If I call curl directly in the terminal I get back a valid token. When I use the os.system() I get returned NULL for the token. Our server at work only lets me run Python2 so I cannot use subprocess.run() as a solution. Here is the call, Any thoughts?

```
os.system('curl -s http://SeverName:Port/api/tokens?userLogin=Login&password=Password >  /home/debug/logs/Lee/test.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **requests** library to do this.

To install:

```
pip install requests
```

To use:

```
import requests

params = {
"userLogin": "Login",
"password": "Password"
}

response = requests.get("http://SeverName:Port/api/tokens", params=params)


with open("/home/debug/logs/Lee/test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not do it using os.system("...")

[os.system()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) returns the (encoded) process exit value. 0 means success

use python library like [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead